# Freeze Panes in HTML opened in Excel

Tags: html, excel, vba

My application exports data to Excel as HTML.

It saves the markup of an HTML table in a temporary file (using xls as an extension). It then asks the operating system to open that file using its native application.

Excel can open it without a problem. I have even been able to get some formatting via CSS.

I would like the top x rows not to scroll. I was wondering if there was a way of achieving a "freeze panes" effect? I have tried using the `thead` and `tbody` tags but it does not help.

I am programming this in ActionScript. However the language used to generate the markup in the text file is irrelevant. What is important is the markup itself.

Comment: Have you tried saving an HTML file from excel and seeing if there's any clue in there?

Comment: @TimWilliams: I have, but it doesn't save any frozen-pane info. If I reopen it, there are no frozen panes anymore.

Comment: On checking - I think other option is via the "XML spreadsheet" format (which you can rename from .xml to .xls). However that does give you the "this workbook is in a different format from..." warning when you open it in Excel.

Comment: Yes, I saw that, and it won't be too friendly for my users. :(

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried that myself but this http://jwcooney.com/2011/09/08/generating-excel-documents-through-html-xml-and-css-part-2/ page seems to have an answer

> ..The x:FreezePanes and x:Panes markup in green below tells Excel to
>   Freeze the first row of the document..

x:FreezePanes etc. elements are documented in the "*Microsoft Office HTML and XML Reference*" which you can download at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Aa155477%28office.10%29.aspx

The x:urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel namespace is also known as "*XML Spreadsheet 2000*"